# docker-compose php-apache and elasticsearch not working

Tags: php, docker, symfony, elasticsearch

I am trying to create a small application using php, apache2 and elastic search, along with kibana

here is my docker settings

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: web
    ports:
        - 8000:80
    volumes:
        - .:/var/www/html/hellofresh
    environment:
        - ELASTIC_SEARCH_HOST=elasticsearch
        - ELASTIC_SEARCH_PORT=9200
    working_dir: /var/www/html/hellofresh
    networks:
        - elasticsearch-bridge

  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:7.10.1
    container_name: elasticsearch
    restart: always
    environment:
        - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
        - 9200:9200
        - 9300:9300
    volumes:
        - ./elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
        - elasticsearch-bridge

  kibana:
    image: kibana:7.10.1
    container_name: kibana
    restart: always
    ports:
        - 5601:5601
    networks:
        - elasticsearch-bridge

networks:
    elasticsearch-bridge:
        driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile:

```
#install php composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

#install git
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y git
RUN git config --global user.email "myemail@gmail.com" && git config --global user.name "Mohamed"

#install symfony console
RUN curl -sS https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer | bash && mv /root/.symfony/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

When i run **curl localhost:9200** from my host or from inside elasticsearch container, i get a successfully response

But when i try to connect from web container i get
`curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused`

Any idea?

Comment: Try ```curl elasticsearch:9200``` from the web container.

Comment: Good to hear your problem is solved. I voted close as this was just a naming error that is not really reproducible for the future. Have a good day.